# In built AEC Android performance

Tags: android, webrtc, speex, aec

Does anyone know if the in-built AEC that ships with Android post Jelly Bean works well? I am trying it and the output I get is very low in volume and very choppy. It does cancel all the speaker output but the leftover user input via mic is in pretty bad condition.

Just wanted to know if the AEC itself sucks or if I screwed up somewhere in the code. I could provide the generated audio file if someone wants to listen to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in AEC might defer to a hardware based AEC, so it's really tough to say what performance you can expect. Note that the webrtc.org reference code has a built-in AEC that works very well, at some (software) processing cost.  If the Android device doesn't have hardware AEC anyway, that cost isn't cumulative.

Because of this, I don't think you can rely very much on consistent performance if you don't know the device beforehand.